# Couldn't install make

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, software-installation, make

I try to install make on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server

```
apt-get install make
```

But I observe error:
 `Temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com`

```
Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_3.81-8.1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
```

Could you describe me what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that linux can't resolve any ip addresses. Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` file if there are any nameservers. Ubuntu will replace the content of the file when it gets a new dhcp request. If you want to have a quick fix add the following lines at the top of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

this will add googles public dns servers to your linux. If you want to configure these nameservers permanently simply add the following line `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` to your network configuration `/etc/network/interfaces`. In the end the configuration might look similar to this:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    // [....]
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

if the file is empty except of the lo device add the following lines:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

(the default network device will be configured through dhcp).